# Old projects are not building after changing SDK path in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently, I uninstalled my SDK from  location `/Users/Shared/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk` and installed in `/usr/local/android_sdk/sdk`
and the same changes I made in Android Studio Settings
Configure->Project Default->Project Structure->Platform Settings->SDK

Now, The problem is with these changes I can build any new project but when I open my old project It gives me this error:

```
Gradle 'GPSProvider' project refresh failed:
           Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.
           Build file '/Users/zohrakhan/AndroidStudioProjects/GPSProvider/GPSProvider/build.gradle' line: 9
           A problem occurred evaluating project ':GPSProvider'.
           A problem occurred evaluating project ':GPSProvider'.
           The SDK directory '/Users/Shared/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk' does not exist.
```

Please help me to find out the problem.

Edit 1:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

Comment: can you please post the content of your build.gradle file?

Comment: did you by any chance update your Android Studio (not the sdk) and after the update your old builds strated failing?

Comment: Thanks Mario for your time. With Lassana answer my problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `local.properties` file (in `/Users/zohrakhan/AndroidStudioProjects/GPSProvider/GPSProvider`directory). This file may contain:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/Shared/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk
```

So, just replace `sdk.dir` property.

Comment: If you close your project and reopen it, it should have detected there was no SDK at the place specified in local.properties, and it should have offered to correct the situation for you.

Comment: @scott It takes me to gradle settings window.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an Old project and you were using different sdk that time Do the following before import

1. Delete all the content of .idea directory inside the project directory
2. Open Studio and import the project and wait until it sync with gradle.
3. If it gives gradle version related error while sync, update your build.gradle file with whaever version your error message is suggesting.

Now do mentioned below to update your local.propertiesfile

Sync your project with Gradle it will automatically ask if there are any conflicts in your sdk paths in project .

Choose default project sdk to use from dialog.

**This is introduced from Android Studio 0.3.7**

Comment: Yes tried that but it did not work. I tried gradlew clean && gradlew build. With lassana answer its working fine.

Comment: which version of studio are you using ?

Comment: version : 0.2.8 A problem occurred evaluating project ':BMTC'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/Shared/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk' does not exist. This error comes up.

Comment: @ZohraKhan you are using very older version of AS, i recommend you to update it, things are improved alot in current releases.

Comment: But when I go In updates and click Check now for new updates  it says You have the latest version of Android I/O preview installed.

Comment: @Zohar make sure you are not connected to any restricted network first. In pop up dialog for update message click on Updates hyper link and let me know the channel you have selected.If nothing helps go to http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest and download the respective zip. Replace everything except sdk in earlier installation directory.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still not working. Android Studio version 0.4.2 I am working on MAC. When I try ./gradlew clean A problem occurred evaluating project ':GPSProvider'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/Shared/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk' does not exist.

Comment: Before importing delete the content of `.idea` directory inside your project and check because all you paths are mentioned there and saved with individual projects.

Comment: Failed to refresh Gradle project 'GPSProviderProject'
           Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.9.
           Please fix the project's Gradle settings. now this error comes

Comment: might be you created the project with gradle 1.6 earlier . you must update all your build.gradle files to point gradle 1.9  as  gradle 1.6 is no more supported by AS 0.4.2 . change  0.6.+ to 0.7.+

Comment: Updated my answer so it can help others as well.